# Submit a form using jquery without navigating to another screen

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to make it so that a form submit doesn't cause the page to navigate and use ajaxSubmit to submit the content. however when I click the submit button, it still navigates to the page in the action attribute of the form. Heres the javascript:

```
var options = {
    success: processLogin
};
$('#loginform').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

and heres the form:

```
<form id='loginform' action='login.php' method='post'>
    <table id='logintable'>
        <tr>
            <td>Room:</td>
            <td><input id='roomname' type='text' name='roomname' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nickname:</td>
            <td><input id='nickname' type='text' name='nickname' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' class='center'><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></td>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29)

```
$('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change the input html tag to `<input id="save" type="Button" value="submit" />` which gives you a button that does nothing except provide a javascript hook.

Use the following javascript to ajax submit your form

```
$("#save").click(function() {
    $("#loginform").ajaxSubmit();
}
```

In doing this you lose the ability to submit the form by pressing enter.  You can overcome this with the following piece of jquery:

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#save").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: what happens when someone presses enter on the form?